# Is there any way to create multiple browser processes for one web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opera

I'm trying to create web page, on which you can browse several geometry models, which sizes are large (and also complexity of some of them is very high) and when i'm trying to load them browsers are just stopping the process(it's seems like browsers have some kind of limit on one process), so now i want to create one process for each geometry and then load them on one web page.

Is there any way to create multiple processes in web browser for one page?

Comment: What if you use an iframe for each model/process?

Comment: But it still will be one process for browser.

Comment: Sure, but if one fails to load, it may not cause the others to fail too. It may force them to load and behave like individual processes instead of one large process.

Comment: Also, I don't know if there are any calculations done, or merely a large set of data-points, but in case of any calculations, maybe you can execute some of those server-side, instead of client-side? Therefore creating 2 processes instead of one.

Comment: Well iframe runs in same process as main html, so it is useless here. Server processes are using one process in browser, so u need some script on client side tho.